# Difference between paint, paintComponent and paintComponents in Swing

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

What is the actual difference between `paint()`, `paintComponent()` and `paintComponents()` in Java Swing?

I tried to understand what explained in Oracle docs but I am not clear.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- AWT, override `paint()`.
- Swing top-level container (e.g.s are `JFrame`, `JWindow`, `JDialog`, `JApplet` ..), override `paint()`.  But there are a number of good reasons *not* to paint in a TLC.  A subject for a separate question, perhaps.
- The rest of Swing (*any component* that derives from `JComponent`), override `paintComponent()`.
- Neither override nor explicitly call `paintComponents()`, leave it to the API to call it when needed.

**Be sure to also use `@Override` notation whenever overriding a method.**

Doing so would hint at the problem of trying to override `paintComponent(..)` in a `JFrame` (it has no such method), which is quite common to see.

Comment: Hi, is paint() function get called immediately after constructor finish execute?

Comment: @GMsoF `repaint()` will be called automatically when needed.  If animating, it might also be called explicitly.  Though called too many times, too quickly, and some calls will be coalesced (ignored).

Comment: also override paint() if you want to draw something on your jpanel subclass that is ABOVE components on the same panel - for example, if GPanel is a your subclass of JPanel, by overriding only paintComponent, your "drawings" will be located behind any components such as buttons, other panels, etc. However, using paint(), you draw "over" the other components.

Answer (score 19):

You may be interested in reading [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

A quote:

> The rules that apply to AWT's lightweight components also apply to Swing components -- for instance, paint() gets called when it's time to render -- except that Swing further factors the paint() call into three separate methods, which are invoked in the following order:

```
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
protected void paintBorder(Graphics g)
protected void paintChildren(Graphics g)
```

> Swing programs should override paintComponent() instead of overriding paint(). Although the API allows it, there is generally no reason to override paintBorder() or paintComponents() (and if you do, make sure you know what you're doing!). This factoring makes it easier for programs to override only the portion of the painting which they need to extend. For example, this solves the AWT problem mentioned previously where a failure to invoke super.paint() prevented any lightweight children from appearing.