# JPanel won't display

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I got a class that's supposed to launch a game (with `main()`), and the game's opening screen. The class with `main()` (named `Starter`), that extends `JFrame`, creates a new `OpeningScreen` class (extending JPanel), and adds it to the JFrame.

For some reason, the `OpeningScreen` won't be added to the JFrame. Code:

`Starter` class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Starter extends JFrame {

    public Starter(){

        setSize(500,500);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Ping-Pong Battle");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        OpeningScreen openingS = new OpeningScreen();
        add(openingS);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Starter starter = new Starter();
    }

}
```

`OpeningScreen` class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class OpeningScreen extends JPanel {

    public OpeningScreen(){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
            setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

        // Soon code here to be drawn.

    }

    public void startGame(){
        Board board = new Board();
    }

}
```

What's the problem? Thanks

EDIT: The constructor of OpeningScreen does run, but doesn't paint the background black. Also, trying to draw things in paint() doesn't work.

Comment: Try overriding `paintComponent(Graphics g)` instead of `paint(Graphics g)`

Comment: nope, same problem :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem arises from overriding `paint` in your `OpeningScreen` class. The background is not drawn because you never draw it! Call `super.paint(g)` to fix this.

However, it is [generally recommended to use paintComponent() instead of paint().](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389187/difference-between-paint-paintcomponent-and-paintcomponents-in-swing) Just move your code to `paintComponent`.

This method correctly draws a black background a red square:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: Okay, forgot the super.paint(g). Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It is typically [recommended](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` as the preferred way of perfoming custom painting...

Answer (score 2):

I think because you override paint() the background doesn't get painted, so it appears like the Panel isn't added. Commenting out the paint method results in the Window being black for me.
Also, drawing in the paint method works for me, maybe your color is set to black so it doesn't show on the black background ? Try g.setColor(Color.white) before drawing.

Comment: I commented out the paint() method, and it worked (black background). But now that I want to draw in the panel, I need to add the paint() method again, and then same problem. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try adding super.paint(g) in the paint method before doing anything else.

Comment: @Josh See my answer. You can do both.