# Game in Java won't respond to key presses

Tags: java, swing, jar

I have just exported a Java game I made to a Runnable JAR.

The game has an opening screen (a class named `OpeningScreen` extending JPanel). When you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, it's supposed to go from the opening screen to the game itself (create a new `Board` instance and add it to the JPanel.)
It works fine inside Eclipse.

An instance of `OpeningScreen` is created in the class with `main()`, named `Starter`.

When exporting, I set the Starter class as the "Launch configuration", and set "Library handling" to "Extract required libararies into generated JAR".

After exporting, I get a window saying that it exported with compile errors, but doesn't tell me which errors exactly.

When starting the program from the generated JAR, the opening screen does show, but pressing ENTER won't start the game, although it does work inside Eclipse.

Here's the code for `OpeningScreen`:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class OpeningScreen extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public OpeningScreen(){
        setFocusable(true);
        setVisible(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

        super.paint(g);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        // A lot of drawing Strings.

    }


    public void startGame(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong Battle");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Board board = new Board();
        frame.add(board);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)startGame();

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }

}
```

EDIT: `Starter` class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Starter extends JFrame {

    public Starter(){

        setSize(500,500);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Pong Battle");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        OpeningScreen openingS = new OpeningScreen();
        add(openingS);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Starter starter = new Starter();
    }

}
```

What could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: 1) For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them. 2) For Swing, it is `paintComponent(Graphics)` rather that `paint(..)` 3) The problem is that the panel is neither focusable nor has focus. 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 5) These same problems come up once or twice a day.  Do you actually *search* the group before asking?

Comment: What do you mean the panel is neither focusable nor has focus? I called setFocusable(true).

Comment: Oh, my bad.  Again, a little louder this time ***For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).***

Comment: Sure, but since your already here could you help me with this?

Comment: Could you post something that actually bloody here?  That collection of rubbish does not, **due to a missing class.**

Comment: BTW - *"I get a window saying that it exported with compile errors"*  That is something you should fix at compile time.  When your 'magic' IDE compiles it, it makes changes to the code so that it can spit out a Jar that will most likely fail!  Totally pointless..

Comment: You mean I need to add Starter? No problem

Comment: I'd fix the compile errors, but I have no idea what they are.

Comment: No, I did not.  To find the missing class, why don't you copy/paste what appears here and try to compile it as a new project?  The compiler will tell you *exactly* what is missing.

Comment: *"but I have no idea what they are."*  You are 'programming by magic'.  Change that, or you'll fail completely.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're saying. I think you're saying that I'm not aware enough of potential compile errors while I code. How could I change this? I have no idea what could cause these compile error and how to avoide them.

Comment: *"How could I change this?"*  Your IDE will show lists of compile errors when you go to compile the code!  What IDE do you use?

Comment: I use Eclipse. Where is the 'compile code' in Eclipse?

Comment: I get no compile errors with code posted, minus the Board class at least. I just deleted that code and works fine.

Comment: If you mean the standard console, I got nothing there after exporting.

Comment: *"I get no compile errors with code posted, minus the Board class at least"* And, do you *really think* I have a `Board` class conveniently lying around, just to help you with your code?  If you are seeing the problems with the lack of the `Board` class, then **that is compile errors.**  BTW - I don't know how to compile in Eclipse, I don't use it often.  But I know it has ways to compile code, and can show the errors.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, that was _my_ comment haha

Comment: @peeskillet  Oh boy.  Is my face red! I should pay closer attention. OP - My bad.

Comment: `but since your already here could you help me with this?` you have already been told that custom painting should be done in the paintComponent() method and you even accepted that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830382/jpanel-wont-display. Why should we continue to help when you just ignore our advice???

Answer (score 0):

Your opening screen needs to be added inside another container and subsequently another Jframe

1. Create another JFrame.
2. Make it undecorated. `f.setUndecorated(true)`
3. Make opening screen panel as content panel `f.setContentPane(new OpeningPanel())`
4. Display this frame.
5. Remove the opening screen frame once <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. `f.dispose()`
6. and then call startGame()

Comment: But an instance of OpeningScreen is added to Starter, which extends JFrame. Is that what you mean?

Comment: required setFocusable for JPanel and/or better to use KeyBIndinds for simple KeyEvents (up to 3key pressed)

Comment: That list goes bad at point 1.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, have to figure out another way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a KeyListener. You should be using Key Bindings.

See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for the reasons why and a working example.