# How to recursively draw lines in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, drawing

I have a project i am struggling to get started with, the core of it is around drawing lines recursively perpendicular to one another. I am rather terrible at GUIs for a start. This is what i have so far but i don't know how to implement a recursive method that will draw the lines. This is what i have so far, just simple code to draw a line:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Test extends JPanel{
    private static String n;
    private static String r;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //n = args[0];
        //r = args[1];
        //System.out.println("THIS IS MY N: " + n);
        //System.out.println("THIS IS MY R: " + r);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.add(new Test());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        int nn = 10;
        for(int i = 0; i < nn; i++){
            g.drawLine(400, 200, 50, 250);
        } 
    }
}
```

So i was thinking along the lines of something like this to do the recursive drawing of the lines:

```
public static void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
 if(count == 20){
  //Stop or some other condition
 }else{
  g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  drawLine(x1+5, y1+5, x2+10, y2+10);
  }
 }
```

I'm not sure how the paint method actually works into it. I don't think i fully grasp what the paint method is actually doing

Comment: I can not see any recursive code.  What do you think the functionality of your recursive code would be?

Comment: I don't have any recursive code as of yet. I would like to know how to create code that would enable me to recursively draw lines. The code above is my initial attempt in just trying to draw a line, i would like to add to it to be able to recursively draw a number of lines

Comment: Sam - You have to think about, what is a recursive method and how would it apply to your request?

Comment: Ideally it would be a method that would take the 4 parameters of the line and keep calling itself whilst adding the parameters until it had reached a certain count.

Comment: OK, now change your question to show a prototype of this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paint()` method is the method that is called every time the component is being painted. This will happen initially, when the frame is resized, when the `repaint()` method is called, etc. In this case you will want to use [`paintComponent()` over `paint()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389187/difference-between-paint-paintcomponent-and-paintcomponents-in-swing). You can save the line as a variable `Line2D.Double` and use it when you paint.

Example code:

```
private static Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double();
private static int count = 100;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // use temp line to not effect original line
    Line2D.Double tempLine = line;
    for (int q = 0; q < count; q++){
        g.drawLine((int)tempLine.x1, (int)tempLine.y1, (int)tempLine.x2, (int)tempLine.y2);
        tempLine = new Line2D.Double(tempLine.x1+5, tempLine.y1+5, 
            tempLine.x2+10, tempLine.y2+10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. So are you storing the line in temp line, drawing it, updating the coordinates while iterating over this process 100 times?

Comment: @Sam yup. Also could you mark this answer as correct so the question is closed