# Override selection color - Jtree

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtree

There is a method in `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` called `setBackgroundSelectionColor()` that allows you to change the selection color when you select an item on a `JTree`. When I went in the source code of `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`, the selection color is set in `paint()` by `getBackgroundSelectionColor()`.

Below in the code, I am attempting to change the selection color by simply overriding the `paint` method. The problem is that the colors remain the same even when set manually in the paint method. Also the method `setBackgroundSelectionColor()` still works even though `getBackgroundSelectionColor()` is no longer used in `paint`.

Why is this and how can I override the colors correctly?
*Without using `setBackgroundSelectionColor()`*

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DirectoryExplorer extends JFrame {
    private DirectoryExplorer() {
        super("Directory Explorer");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        createPanel();
        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        JTree tree = new JTree();

        paintRenderer pR = new paintRenderer();
        tree.setCellRenderer(pR);

        //pR.setBackgroundSelectionColor(Color.RED); //Why does this work when changing value in paint doesn't

        panel.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DirectoryExplorer();
    }

    private class paintRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Color bColor;

            if (selected) {
                bColor = Color.RED;//= getBackgroundSelectionColor();
            } else {
                bColor = getBackgroundNonSelectionColor();
                if (bColor == null) {
                    bColor = getBackground();
                }
            }

            //super.paint(g); //Paints the correct colors but no text

            int imageOffset = -1;
            if (bColor != null) {
                imageOffset = getLabelStart();
                g.setColor(bColor);
                if(getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight()) {
                    g.fillRect(imageOffset, 0, getWidth() - imageOffset, getHeight());
                } else {
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() - imageOffset, getHeight());
                }
            }

            if (hasFocus) {
                if (imageOffset == -1) {
                    imageOffset = getLabelStart();
                }

                if(getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight()) {
                    paintFocus(g, imageOffset, 0, getWidth() - imageOffset, getHeight(), bColor);
                } else {
                    paintFocus(g, 0, 0, getWidth() - imageOffset, getHeight(), bColor);
                }
            }
            super.paint(g); //Paints text but wrong colors
        }

        private void paintFocus(Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h, Color notColor) {
            Color bsColor = Color.RED;//= getBorderSelectionColor();

            if (bsColor != null && selected) {
                g.setColor(bsColor);
                g.drawRect(x, y, w - 1, h - 1);
            }
        }

        private int getLabelStart() {
            Icon currentI = getIcon();
            if(currentI != null && getText() != null) {
                return currentI.getIconWidth() + Math.max(0, getIconTextGap() - 1);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
What it currently looks like

[image]

Comment: it is working fine I guess --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inh6K.png, post a Screensh. of the GUI

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Unfortunately it looks like the photo in the edit for me

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ If it makes a difference using Windows 10 on JDK 8 u112

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I'm guessing it works for you?

Comment: am using java8 windows 10 and eclipse... and it looks like this --> i.stack.imgur.com/Inh6K.png... what about you?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Only difference is I'm not using eclipse to compile. Just using `javac...`, `java...`

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I copied the code off the question onto my laptop to see if I would get a different result but I did not. Are you sure you didn't change anything which fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The problem is that you are overriding `paint(...)` instead of `paintComponent(...)`*

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9391382/4601149) you should not override `paint` for something which is not a top level container in swing, instead, you should override `paintComponent`.

Change the code to look something like this.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
...
super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

For example

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DirectoryExplorer extends JFrame {
    private DirectoryExplorer() {
        super("Directory Explorer");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        createPanel();
        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        JTree tree = new JTree();

        paintRenderer pR = new paintRenderer();
        tree.setCellRenderer(pR);

        panel.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new DirectoryExplorer());
    }

    private class paintRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Color bColor;

            if (selected) {
                bColor = Color.RED;
            } else {
                bColor = getBackgroundNonSelectionColor();
                if (bColor == null) {
                    bColor = getBackground();
                }
            }

            int imageOffset = -1;
            if (bColor != null) {
                imageOffset = getLabelStart();
                g.setColor(bColor);
                if(getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight()) {
                    g.fillRect(imageOffset, 0, getWidth() - imageOffset, getHeight());
                } else {
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() - imageOffset, getHeight());
                }
            }

            if (hasFocus) {
                if (imageOffset == -1) {
                    imageOffset = getLabelStart();
                }

                if(getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight()) {
                    paintFocus(g, imageOffset, 0, getWidth() - imageOffset, getHeight());
                } else {
                    paintFocus(g, 0, 0, getWidth() - imageOffset, getHeight());
                }
            }
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        private void paintFocus(Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
            Color bsColor = Color.RED;

            if (bsColor != null && selected) {
                g.setColor(bsColor);
                g.drawRect(x, y, w - 1, h - 1);
            }
        }

        private int getLabelStart() {
            Icon currentI = getIcon();
            if(currentI != null && getText() != null) {
                return currentI.getIconWidth() + Math.max(0, getIconTextGap() - 1);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```