# Why is paintComponent drawing the circle many times?

Tags: java

I need to make a circle look like it is bouncing but the output I get is many circles instead of only one moving. How can I make paint component only draw one circle during the animation instead of showing me several balls as it moves?

```
class thePanel extends JPanel {
    int radius;
    int diameter;
    int x;
    int y;
    int dx;
    int dy;
    int timerInterval = 10;
    Timer timer;

thePanel() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    dx = 3;
    dy = 3;
    radius = 20;
    diameter = radius * 2;
    timer = new Timer(timerInterval, new TimerListener());
    timer.start();
    repaint();
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawRect(getWidth() / 2, 0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
    g.drawOval(this.x - radius, this.y - radius, diameter, diameter);
}

public void fixPosition() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    if (x < radius)
        dx = Math.abs(dx);
    if (x > getWidth() - radius) 
        dx = -Math.abs(dx);
    if (y < radius) 
        dy = Math.abs(dy);
    if (y > getHeight() - radius) 
        dy = -Math.abs(dy);
}

class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       fixPosition();
       repaint();
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: It looks like a typo, try `super.paintComponent(g)` instead of `super.paintComponents(g)`  .

Comment: How shall I clear it?

Comment: Clear the background with `g.setColor(); g.drawRect()`.  Cover the full area.

Comment: Haha! true @Arnaud! Thank you!

Comment: difference between paint, paintcomponent and paintcomponents:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389187/difference-between-paint-paintcomponent-and-paintcomponents-in-swing