# PaintComponent don't seem to get call or to show

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

My problem is really simple : I have this little program, and it just don't show the red box I'm trying to make :

**Main**

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Affichage a = new Affichage();
        a.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Affichage :**

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Affichage extends Frame{
    public Affichage(){
        setTitle("Exo 1 : Galerie");
        setSize(1120,560);
        Graphique graph = new Graphique();
        this.add(graph);
    }
}
```

**Graphique :**

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Graphique extends JComponent {
    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics pinceau = g.create();

        pinceau.setColor(Color.RED);
        pinceau.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);

        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

I bet it's ridicule but I can't find what it is, help me.
PS : yes the test don't get print too

Comment: You need to override ``paintComponent()`` rather than ``paintComponents()``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a Swing component (`javax.swing.JComponent`) to an AWT frame (`java.awt.Frame`). Noone will call the `paintComponents()` method, that's why you don't get any output or result. Extend from `javax.swing.JFrame` instead, so you have a Swing frame with a Swing component.

Comment: @LucaAntoine You should use `paintComponent()` (without the "s"), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389187/difference-between-paint-paintcomponent-and-paintcomponents-in-swing

Answer (score 1):

Actually, don't extend `JFrame` as it is bad practice.  Just make an instance of it.  To paint, extend `JPanel` and override `paintComponent`.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.add(new MyPanel());

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   // other stuff
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);  
       // painting stuff.
   }
}
```

And remember not to mix `Swing` and `AWT` components.